# I want to transfer the date I selected to mainactivity but "date" is always empty

Tags: android

This is code of Calender and I want to select it and it can be sent to mainactivity

```
public class CalendarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CalendarView calendarView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);
    calendarView=(CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            String date=year+"/"+month+1+"/"+dayOfMonth;
            Intent intent=new Intent(CalendarActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("date",date);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

the part of code :

```
  String date=getIntent().getStringExtra("date");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: The code looks good. Try " Invalidate crashes and restart" .. Sometimes it happens. Your code is not working ...

Comment: @Sheng, find my answer and try, You doing one small mistake in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using bundle :

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("date", date);
intent.putExtra(extras);
```

MainActivity :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String date = extras.getString("date");
```

Comment: not working. I dont see how bundle could help solve my problem

Comment: Are you calling the activity from Main Activity itself or not. If you do, you can use the return intent and pass the data from the calendar activity back to main activity. Or maybe the data that you sent to the activity is really null. try to display the data first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`Long date;
date = calendarview.getDate();`

and then pass date to other activity.

Comment: still not working.view is used instead of "calenderview"cuz it is defined in the methods

Comment: take date =  calendarView.getDate() in onSelectedDayChange() method.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to send information to an activity. You could do something like this

```
// Make the bundle     
Bundle args = new Bundle();
// Give the bundle a string
args.putString("date", new Gson().toJson(date, Date.class));
```

Now you can get your bundle from you activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
// Retrieve sent bundle
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();

// Try to get the dateSelected that was sent as a string
String dateJson = savedInstanceState.getString("date", "");

// Convert our string to an object
Date date = new Gson().fromJson(dateJson, Date.class);

// Do whatever you want with your date object
// you should also use a SimpleDateFormat to print dates 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 ...       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

When you set date in intent write this:

```
String date=year+"/"+month+1+"/"+dayOfMonth;
Intent intent=new Intent(CalendarActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
intent.putStringExtra("date",date);
startActivity(intent);
```

After write below in another activity where you want to get date in string format:

```
String date = getIntent().getStringExtra("date");
```